# Search disk C: or D: in Nuget.Config

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a following Nuget.Config file in which I specify path to nuget packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="SomeKey" value="D:\...\somePath" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

However this configuration targets disk D: directly and I would like to target disk C: or disk D:. Or if it does not find such on disk C: it would search for it on disk D:. I could not find such solution in documentation and truth be told I have never stumbled upon such solution in any path configuration in any language or framework. But it would be quite handy one. Thank you in advance

Comment: In Visual Studio you can select "All" as the package source, so surely you would just add two package sources, one for C and one for D? Or am I missing something?

Comment: And that will work? Won't they conflict? I would have to repeat the same key. I thought that is not allowed.

Comment: Why not just give it a different key?

Comment: It doesn't matter as well? I am sorry, I was not aware. If you want please post your reply as an answer and I will mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add two package sources, one for each drive:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="SomeKey" value="D:\...\somePath" />
        <add key="SomeOtherKey" value="C:\...\somePath" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Then in the NuGet package manager, you can either choose to search "All" (i.e. NuGet, SomeKey, and SomeOtherKey), or choose a specific one to search:

[image]